Dynamically update column count based on child content with max-height on grid items?
I am working on a CSS Grid layout where all child elements (buttons) must have the same width and height.
I want the number of columns should automatically adjust based on the content of the child elements.
Each chile element has a max-height and a minimum-width set on them:
In the following snippet, the content of the third button is overflowing its element. My goal is for the content to fit within the element without exceeding the max-height, while ensuring all sibling elements maintain the same width. The number of columns should adjust accordingly to prevent overflow.
Fiddle


.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(130px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    gap: 10px;
    max-width: 500px;
}

button {
    max-height: 80px;
}
<div class="container">
  <button>
    <div>Button 1</div>
    <p>Description 1</p>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div>Button 2</div>
    <p>Description 2</p>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div>Button 3</div>
    <p>Description 3 Description 3 Description 3 Description 3 Description 3</p>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div>Button 4</div>
    <p>Description 4</p>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div>Button 5</div>
    <p>Description 5</p>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div>Button 6</div>
    <p>Description 6</p>
  </button>
</div>



These are the rules:

All buttons should always remain identical in size (width and height).
The items height should never exceed 80px.
Minimum item width is 130px

Is it something that can be achieved using CSS grid? if not what can be an alternative solution?

Please add more details and clarity to your question. It is unclear what you're asking or trying to achieve.

What is supposed to happen when the content exceeds the max-height? "All buttons should remain identical in size (width and height), and the number of columns should adjust accordingly." - This already happens, so your issue is unclear.

Indeed. the text overflows and that can be removed with overflow hidden

If you have fixed max-height what result do you expect with third button?

The only question seems to be whether you want the content of the overflowing button to be available to the user or not. Assuming it's there for a reason, add overflow: auto so it can scroll when needed.

You can achieve this easily with flexbox if you are open to that.

@Paulie_D I want that the column amount should change to 2

@Meet, yes I'm open to it. Mind sharing a code example in an answer?

@Paulie_D, I just edited the answer to clarify what I'm aiming for

The issue is what is supposed to happen to the content that overflows at 80px. The rest of your requirements are already met.

The item width should expand and effect the total column amount.

So are you saying that button 3 should get as wide as it needs to to show the content, regardless of e.g. the width available in the viewport?

The issue I'm trying to solve is when there's no limited viewport. The content of the button should spread it's width, which will then effect/reduce the amount of the columns

If there's no limit to the width of the parent, why won't all the columns fit into it? Somehow you are assuming a limit but I don't know what it is. Without knowing the width how does the system know how many columns can fit in?

Please see my code snippet above. Why is the content of  Button 3 overflowing?

Button 3 is overflowing because you haven't told it not to wrap. Also container hasn't been given a width so it's assumed the width of the viewport (on my wide screen button 3 does not overflow as there's just enough room for all the buttons plus gaps). You need to explain what the overall width is to be.

I added now max-width: 500px to the container. Currently it contains 3 buttons due to grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(130px, 1fr)). I would want that the button content should force it to 2 columns or 1 if needed. I'm not sure this is possible with grid, and I wonder what are the alternative css-only solutions. Thanks.

There is no way that I know of to achieve your stated goal.
Column widths in a CSS grid are totally controlled by grid-template-columns. Certain values for grid-template-columns will consider the content width of your grid items, such as auto, min-content and max-content, but none of these are suitable for your scenario.
My recommendation is to get rid of your max-height and instead increase the minimum column width (the value 130px in your grid-template-columns declaration) in order to reduce your button heights.
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));

If your buttons contain widely varying amounts of text, perhaps a different layout would be better. You could consider a masonry layout. Browser support for doing this in CSS is still a while away, but you can do it if you are prepared to fix your button heights, otherwise you can use a Javascript library.


body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.masonry {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 10px;
  gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #fff;
}

.item1 { grid-row: span 7; background-color: #ff6f61; }
.item2 { grid-row: span 8; background-color: #6b5b95; }
.item3 { grid-row: span 15; background-color: #88b04b; }
.item4 { grid-row: span 8; background-color: #d65076; }
.item5 { grid-row: span 7; background-color: #ffb347; }
.item6 { grid-row: span 7; background-color: #45b8ac; }
.item7 { grid-row: span 8; background-color: #e94b3c; }
.item8 { grid-row: span 8; background-color: #6c5b7b; }
.item9 { grid-row: span 7; background-color: #00a86b; }
.item10 { grid-row: span 7; background-color: #b565a7; }
<div class="masonry">
  <button class="item item1">
    <p>Button 1</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </button>
  <button class="item item2">
    <p>Button 2</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </button>
  <button class="item item3">
    <p>Button 3</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante.</p>
  </button>
  <button class="item item4">
    <p>Button 4</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </button>
  <button class="item item5">
    <p>Button 5</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </button>
  <button class="item item6">
    <p>Button 6</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </button>
  <button class="item item7">
    <p>Button 7</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </button>
  <button class="item item8">
    <p>Button 8</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </button>
  <button class="item item9">
    <p>Button 9</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </button>
  <button class="item item10">
    <p>Button 10</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </button>
</div>




either add overflow:hidden to your button, it will keep the max-height and cut your description accordingly, or remove the button css completely so all buttons will take the same height as the one with the largest description.


.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(130px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    gap: 10px;
}
<div class="container">
  <button>
    <div>Button 1</div>
    <p>Description 1</p>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div>Button 2</div>
    <p>Description 2</p>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div>Button 3</div>
    <p>Description 3 Description 3 Description 3 Description 3 Description 3</p>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div>Button 4</div>
    <p>Description 4</p>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div>Button 5</div>
    <p>Description 5</p>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div>Button 6</div>
    <p>Description 6</p>
  </button>
</div>



